# Detect mouse button event on movement in query

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm trying to detect whether a mouse button is already pressed if it moves over an element. 
In safari, the mouse event changes if buttons are pressed.  Firefox doesn't.

This fiddle/snippet explains it better : 
In Safari/Chrome the boxes turn blue when rolled over (event = 0), but turn red if rolled over with: the left button depressed (event=1).
In Firefox it's always red (event=1).  I kind of think that Firefox is correct as the event is triggered on the mouseover.

The problem is I need Firefox to behave like Safari/Chrome!

http://jsfiddle.net/robertireland/5w5rxrhy/

```js
$('td').mouseover(function(e) {
    
    
    $(this).removeClass();
    $('#button').text(e.which);
 
    if(e.which==0){
        $(this).addClass('bgblue');
    }
    
    if(e.which==1){
        $(this).addClass('bgred');
    }
});
```

```css
#output {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;  
}
td{padding:10px; border:1px dotted #ccc; cursor:pointer;}
.bgred{background-color:red;}
.bgblue{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    
</table>
<div id="output">Button pressed: <span id="button"></span></div>
```

Comment: First of all, I think `mouseenter` would be more appropriate in this case to prevent bubbling. Secondly, upon firing the event and hitting your conditionals, check `mousedown`.

Comment: thanks for educating me on bubbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could just keep track of a flag that indicates whether the mouse is down, and check it during the `mouseover` event:

```js
var isMouseDown = false;

$('body').mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;  
});

$('td').mouseover(function(e) {
    
    $(this).removeClass();
    $('#button').text(e.which);
 
    if (isMouseDown){
        $(this).addClass('bgred');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('bgblue');
    }
});
```

```css
#output {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;  
}
td{padding:10px; border:1px dotted #ccc; cursor:pointer;}
.bgred{background-color:red;}
.bgblue{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    
</table>
<div id="output">Button pressed: <span id="button"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler answer..

```
$('td').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass();
    $('#button').text(e.which);
    if( e.which==1 && $('body').mousedown() ){
        $(this).addClass('bgred');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('bgblue');
    }
});
```